# Latest Google Chrome stable not firing onhashchange event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, google-chrome-frame

I've noticed in the past week or possibly a little more google chrome has stopped firing onhashchange events after the first hashchange has been fired.  Firefox +  IE 8 and 9 work as expected and chrome did work.  Has anybody else noticed this?  I can't supply an example but could mock one up if necessary.  Im running Google Chrome Version 19.0.1084.46.  This also occurs in Google Chrome Frame which is suggesting its the latest update of V8 or something similar.

I've also tried in Chrome Beta V 20.0.1132.17 and it behaves as i'd expect, the same as firefox and IE.

The hash actually changes in the URL bar but nothing happens.

Comment: Have tried on a machine that hadn't updated chrome, was on version 18.something and it works fine.

Comment: For anyone who is interested I've logged a bug with google chromes dev team here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129977&thanks=129977&ts=1338186579